# If $\lim_{x \to \infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert = L > 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ or $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -L$.

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert = L > 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ or $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -L$.

Is the above cailm true? I suspect it's false but I can't find a counter example! How should I approach such claims?

Thank you so much!((:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is false, unless you know something more about $f$ or $L$. Consider any *positive* $L$ and consider $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}L & x\text{ is an integer}\\-L & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Now, if $f$ is *continuous* at sufficiently large $x$ (regardless of the value of $L$) or if $L=0$ (regardless of the continuity of $f$), then the claim is true.

Comment: But if $x = 0.5$ then $\lvert f(x) \rvert = \lvert -L \rvert = L$ and then the claim is true

Comment: We're not evaluating $f$. Rather, the claim says exactly that: $$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists M_\epsilon:\forall x>M_\epsilon,\left\lvert f(x)-L\right\rvert<\epsilon.$$ Put into words, we can make $f(x)$ as close to $L$ as we like, by making $x$ sufficiently large.

Comment: This function is not continuous when L is non zero

Comment: @Idris: True.... What are you getting at?

Comment: I don't get it... There is no limit to the $f(x)$ you suggested

Comment: @Lisa: The function I described does *not* meet the required conditions. Letting $\epsilon=L,$ then no matter how large we make $M,$ there is some integer $n>M.$ If $x=n,$ then $f(x)=-L$ is not within $\epsilon$ of $-L.$ On the other hand, if $x=n+\frac12,$ then $f(x)=-L,$ is not within $\epsilon$ of $L.$ Hence, neither $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ nor $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-L$ holds. In fact, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist, and yet $\lim_{x\to\infty}\lvert f(x)\rvert=L.$

Comment: Ohhh now I get it!! When the function is absolute there is a limit, and when it's not there isn't!

Comment: @Lisa: Precisely!

Answer (score 6):

Not True, set $L = 1$, and define
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \text{ is rational, } \\
-1 & x \text{ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$